# Can not create hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, centos6

I am following  http://alanxelsys.com/hadoop-v2-single-node-installation-on-centos-6-5 to install hadoop
on my cluster

I have installed hadoop inside /usr/local/hadoop/sbin directory and when I try executing the bash script

```
start-all.sh; system gives below error;
start-all.sh: command not found
```

Know  What I have  tried

```
1. Tried  setting SSH again
2. Recheck the java path
```

Varible i have set is

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Comment: so did you ssh'd into the server and tried to execute `java`?

Comment: Did you try to go manually into sbin directory and try to execute that command ?

Comment: did you source .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

The start-all.sh script says that "This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh" so you should use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh